# Rでパッケージのインストール後に利用できない

Tags: r

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

rvestをインストールしたのですが、その後エラーがでてしまいます。
xml2をロードできないと書いていますが、どのような原因でしょうか。
解決策も含めて教えていただけると嬉しいです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: `xml2` パッケージはインストールされていますか？ `rvest` パッケージと同時にインストールされるはずですが…　`install.packages("rvest")` を再度実行すると何かエラーが出ているかもしれません。`xml2` 自身はが必要とするlibxml2がインストールされているかも見てみてください。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。投稿内容を修正してインストールを再度実行したときの画像を載せました。しかし、エラーがでます。また、ミラーサイトは日本語のものにしました。どのように処理すればよいでしょうか？

Comment: 今回のような場合にはできれば画面キャプチャではなく、実行したコマンドや表示されたメッセージをそのまま文字として質問文に貼り付けてもらった方が読み手にとって親切かなと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。以後気を付けます。> install.packages("rvest")
 パッケージを ‘C:/Users/みきてぃー/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’ 中にインストールします 
 (‘lib’ が指定されていないため) 
 --- このセッションで使うために、CRAN のミラーサイトを選んでください --- 
 URL 'https://cran.ism.ac.jp/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/rvest_0.3.5.zip' を試しています 
Content type 'application/zip' length 664006 bytes (648 KB)
downloaded 648 KB

 パッケージ ‘rvest’ は無事に展開され、MD5 サムもチェックされました 

 ダウンロードされたパッケージは、以下にあります 
        C:\Users\みきてぃー\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpyA6dCB\downloaded_packages 
> library(rvest)
 要求されたパッケージ xml2 をロード中です 
 エラー:  パッケージ ‘xml2’ をロードできませんでした 
> 
このようなメッセージでした。